# What are the restrictions of Grails' mockDomain() method?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, grails-orm, spock

I'm writing a Spock Spec (unit test) for a Service in Grails 1.3.5, and I've run across the following error:

```
No signature of method: myapp.Thing.findAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[sort:index, order:asc]] Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure), getAll(java.util.List), getAll([Ljava.lang.Object;)

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: myapp.Thing.findAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[sort:index, order:asc]]
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure), getAll(java.util.List), getAll([Ljava.lang.Object;)
    at grails.test.MockUtils.addDynamicFinders_closure56(MockUtils.groovy:641)
    at myapp.MyService.getCards(MyService.groovy:8)
    at myapp.MyServiceSpec.getCards returns empty map if no cards or statuses are available(MyServiceSpec.groovy:13)
```

Previously this test passed, but the failure occurred when I modified my Service to include sorting of results in the `getThings()` method.

```
class MyService {
    static transactional = true

    static getThings() {
        Thing.findAll(sort: 'index', order: 'asc')
    }
}
```

This still appears to work when the application is run, so I suspect it's a limitation of the implementation of `mockDomain()`.

```
class MyServiceSpec extends UnitSpec {
    def 'mockDomain has some limits, i suspect'() {
        given:
            mockDomain(Thing)
            def myService = new MyService()
        when:
            myService.getThings()
        then:
            true
    }
}
```

---

So my question is are their differences in the methods added to a domain class using `mockDomain()` as opposed to using the real domain class at runtime?  If so, what are they?

Comment: Wanted to tag with SPOCK but I don't have enough rep to create the tag.

Answer (score 3):

`sort` and `order` are Hibernate criteria parameters, they won't work with `MockDomain()` - it doesn't involve Hibernate. Luckily.

You can mock that `findAll()` signature yourself, using instances array - the second parameter of `MockDomain()`, (**EDIT**) like, this overrides `findAll(Map)` signature of `Thing`:

```
List<Thing> thingInstances = []

void setUp() {
    mockDomain(Thing, thingInstances)

    Thing.metaClass.`static`.findAll = { Map m ->
        def result = thingInstances.sort{ it."${m.order}" }
        m.order == 'asc' ? result : result.reverse()
    }
}
```

(**EDIT** end)

Or you can make it integration test, then it will run for ages. Which I don't recommend.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realise the Hibernate/GORM distinction.  How can I add the `findAll()` method to `mockDomain()`'s arguments?  I understood the second arg was instances of `Thing` that will appear in the domain, rather than methods to add to Thing.

Comment: that makes me feel a little sick :-(  Do I have to do this in every test?

Comment: Only in those that test methods with `order` an `sort`. Or you can create an own `GrailsUnitTestCase` descendant. Or extend `GrailsUnitTestCase.mockDomain()` in your bootstrap. Sorry, I know no better way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new approach for mocking domain objects: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/New-approach-to-mocking-domain-classes-in-Grails-unit-tests-td2529895.html. Maybe this helps you out here.